# "Missing required 'ldap' module (pip install python-ldap)

Tags: python, ansible, macos-mojave

I am running osx-mojave and I am trying to run ansible with the ldap-module.

However, when I try to run it like this

```
ansible-playbook play.yml
```

I get this error

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [create the account] ***************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Missing required 'ldap' module (pip install python-ldap)."}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/testuser/adtest/play.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have searched similar questions on this site and I cant find a solution to this.

I have run

`pip install python-ldap`

and

`sudo pip install python-ldap`

This is the output

`Requirement already satisfied: python-ldap in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in /Users/testuser/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-ldap) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-ldap) (0.2.5)`

It doesn't solve the problem.

The output of `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze 
awscli==1.16.132 
botocore==1.12.122 
colorama==0.3.9 
docutils==0.14 
jmespath==0.9.4 
ldap3==2.6 
pbr==5.2.1 
pyasn1==0.4.5 
pyasn1-modules==0.2.5 
python-dateutil==2.8.0 
python-ldap==3.2.0 
python3-ldap==0.9.8.4 
PyYAML==3.13 rsa==3.4.2 
s3transfer==0.2.0 
six==1.12.0 
stevedore==1.30.1 
urllib3==1.24.1 
virtualenv==16.6.0 
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3 
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
```

If anyone has a solution for this please let me know.

Comment: Added to the question - see output

Comment: What happens if you go into a python terminal and type `import python-ldap`?

Comment: Is ansible executing python in a different virtual environment? Maybe that environment doesn't have the ldap package installed.

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import python-ldap
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import python-ldap
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you print the value of `ansible_python_interpreter`, or is if undefined?

Comment: Don't laugh, but how do I do that?

Comment: You can use the debug module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html

Comment: Please update the question with your playbook. content of play.yml

Answer (score 0):

your computer might not recognize the command python or pip,

try looking up how to get your osx computer to recognize the pip or python command
from the terminal.

sorry i'm not an osx guy sorry.

Comment: pip is working, and it shows that it installs the ldap module.  python and python3 work also when I enter them on cmdline

Comment: try going into the command line and reinstalling the module if it is installed it will say "Requirement already satisfied"